# Interpolation in an attribute erb with simple form (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, erb, string-interpolation

I'm working with Ruby on Rails and I have a simple form gem that is like this:

> Code problem

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admins, @calendar_entry],
                    url: toggle_visibility_admins_calendar_entry_path(calendar_entry),
                    method: :patch,
                    remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :visible,
                    id: 'switch-sm-#{calendar_entry.id.to_s}',
                    class: 'switch',
                    type: 'checkbox' %>
<% end %>
```

And it gets the following output in HTML (check the **id attribute in input**):

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_calendar_entry" id="new_calendar_entry" action="/admins/calendar_entries/35/toggle_visibility" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input id="switch-sm-#{calendar_entry.id.to_s}" class="boolean optional switch" type="checkbox" value="1" name="calendar_entry[visible]">
</form>
```

Ignoring the `remote: true` and all the attributes in the simple form, the real problem is the **interpolation** in the **id attribute**, for any reason I don't get the data of the variable, however, I can do this way:

> Bad code by standards

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admins, @calendar_entry],
                    url: toggle_visibility_admins_calendar_entry_path(calendar_entry),
                    method: :patch,
                    remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :visible,
                    id: 'switch-sm-'+calendar_entry.id.to_s,
                    class: 'switch',
                    type: 'checkbox' %>
<% end %>
```

And yes, this second code works, but I want to do it by the first option, by **interpolation**, so my question is:

### **Is there a reason why I'm not getting the data with interpolation in the "code problem"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double quotes when performing string interpolation and do not need to call `to_s` (it will automatically be converted to a string)....

```
id: "switch-sm-#{calendar_entry.id}"
```

Comment: Ohhh! It works the way you said it! Thanks, bro! I didn't know that!